# How do I get the window object of a page from Vimperator?

Tags: javascript, firefox, vimperator

I'm using:

- Firefox 46
- Vimperator 3.13

I want to use [Vimperator](http://www.vimperator.org/vimperator/) to inject javascript inside a webpage, a bit like Grease Monkey would do, but by using Vimperator and its `:js` command.

But the Vimperator `:js` command and the current html page have different scopes, and I can't find out how to ref to the current page `window` object, from `:js`.

For example, if I open the Firefox web console, and I run:

```
window.myvar = 10
```

Then, if I run the following inside the Vimperator's toolbar:

```
:js alert(window.myvar)
```

, then it displays `undefined`.

So, how do I get the current page `window` object from Vimperator?

Answer (score 1):

## Use `content`.

Use `content`. Eg. The document rendered in the current tab is `content.document`.

Incidentally, the top-level object you get with `window` represents the Firefox GUI.

### warning:

There's an ancient bug in both Vimperator and Pentadactyl that crashes Firefox if you try to use Vimperator's command-line autocompletion on the `content` object. Since it triggers automatically (unless you disable it), this means you can't even type `content.` in the command-line - it will trigger the autocompletion and immediately crash the browser.

What you have to do instead is either paste in the command, or type say, `t.myVar`, and then jump back to fill in the `conten`. (Don't move the cursor directly back over `.` - use <kbd>Home</kbd> or something.) It's really a pain in the arse, but there it is.

You can use autocompletion once you're deeper in, just not with `content`.

If you need to explore the window object, you have to do it in another tool - Firebug, developer tools, etc... Browser Console (C-S-J) is a good choice since it matches what you see in Vimperator closely.

#### workaround

You could use a key binding like this:

```
:cmap <C-w> <Home>echo content.<End>
```

Then, if you open the command line with <kbd>:</kbd>, type `myVar` and press <kbd>C-w</kbd>, it will change the command-line to `echo content.myVar` and place the cursor at the end.
(You can replace `echo` with `js` if you prefer - I find `echo` more convenient.)